# Grafana repeated row, lookup text value in another variable

Tags: grafana

In Grafana I have a dashboard with 3 repeated panels based on 3 specific datapoints:

key1: "/url1", text1: "Title of panel 1"
key1: "/url2", text2: "Title of panel 2"
key1: "/url3", text3: "Title of panel 3"

Basically I want to use the resulting variable as a lookup in another custom variable.

### Define variables in Grafana Dashboard

For now I created a custom variable `panel` defined as "Type: Custom" with values:

```
key1, key2, key3
```

Then I created another custom variable `texts` with key:value pairs defined as such:

```
key1: Title of panel 1, key2: Title of panel 2, key3: Title of panel 3
```

(texts variable should eventually be hidden but I did not hide it yet for debugging purposes)

My idea is to put a title of the repeated panel.

### Define repeated rows on a Grafana Dashboard

Now I want to repeat rows

I just cannot retrieve the values based on the resulting $panel variable.

Now i want to use the value of `panel` variable to lookup the relevant text.

How do I do that?

Here is what I tried so far (with no luck):

```
$texts[$panel] 
$texts{$panel} 
$texts{"$panel"} 
$texts{'$panel'} 
$texts{key = $panel} 
$texts{key = "$panel"} 
$texts{key = '$panel'} 
$texts{key = key2} 
$texts{key2}
```

Unfortunately, all of these examples always give me the first item of the custom variable. In the screenshot you can see all rows have "Title of panel 1".

[image]

So my question is how to lookup the value of a custom variable based on another variable?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?